# C-Matrix-Elements of Main Diagonal and Anti Diagonal Are Same

Tags: c, matrix

**Hello!
My task is to check if the elements of main and anti diagonal of quadratic matrix are same. If this condition is satisfied 'Yes' should be printed; 'No' in the opposite case. For example, the condition is satisfied for matrix 3x3 with all rows equal to: 1 2 3. My code worked for all the matrices except
the one with negative numbers and the one with dimension 5x5 with 4 rows: 1 2 3 4 5
and 5th row: 1 2 3 4 6, and I don't know why. I am beginner. I hope you could help.**

```
      int i,j,M,b=0,m[100][100];
      do{
      printf("Dimension of matrix: ");
      scanf("%d", &M);
      if (M<0 || M>100)
      printf("Wrong input!\n");
      }while (M<0 || M>100);
      printf("Enter the elements: ");
      
      for (i=0;i<M;i++){
      for (j=0;j<M;j++){
      scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
       }
        }  
      for (i=0;i<M;i++){
      for (j=0;j<M;j++){
      if(m[i][j]!=m[M-(i+1)][j])
      b=0;
      else if ((i==j || i+j==M-1) && (m[i][j]==m[M-(i+1)][j]))
      b=1;
      else b=0;
 }
 }
     if(b==1)
     printf("YES");
     else printf("NO");
     }
```

Comment: Hi Michael and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Is `M` really uninitialised when you use it? MRE please.

Comment: Please apply indentation, it makes structure analysis so much easier.

Comment: Perhaps you need to encapsulate the code into seperate functions to make it easier to read and debug. Something like `setMatrix()` with the nested for loops and the read from cin, and `checkMatrix()` to see whether diagonals are equal, maybe even a `getDiagonal()` and `getAntiDiagonal()`.

Comment: I am not allowed to use any special functions or libraries

Comment: I made the changes to for loop, and now the code only doesn't work for matrix 4x4 with negative numbers where m[0][0]=-1 and  m[3][0]=1. It returns Yes instead of No.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by @Bob__, there are a couple of issues with the code:

1. first, in C, array indices start from 0.
2. Furthermore, in your inner loop, over `j`, you only read a single entry but then you try to compare the diagonal entry with the anti-diagonal entry which you haven't read in yet. You probably want to read in the entire matrix first and then, in a separate loop, check whether the diagonal and anti-diagonal are the same.

```c
for (i=0; i < M; i++){
    for (j = 0; j< M; j++){
      scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
    }
}
```

3. Given that array indices in C start at 0, there is a missing pair of parantheses in the matrix index calculation: the index for the anti-diagonal entry should be `m[ M - (i+1) ][j]`. Once you have read in the entire matrix, something like this ought to work:

```c
for(i = 0; i < M; i++){
    if( m[i][i] != m[M - (i+1)][i] ){
        b = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to copy and compile that code, but it did not work for some cases.@hasash

Comment: @Michael Please show how exactly you have changed the program and the exact test cases that produce the wrong outcome.

Comment: I edited the question and added the changes to for loop and included the matrix for which the code doesn't work. @Bob__

Comment: @Michael Compare the snippet at point 3 of this answer with the second nested loop in your program. They are checking if, for every column, the *two* elements of the two diagonals are not equal. It assumes that `b` is initialized as `1` and I'd stop the loop immediately after setting `b = 0;` using a `break;`.

Comment: Bob__ I added the new code to the question, but, now, it doesn't work for 5th and 6th matrix, but this code solved the problem with the previous incorrect answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the main issues in the posted code.

- `if (M<0 || M>100) printf("Wrong input!\n");` I'd argue that a 0-dimensioned matrix wouldn't be acceptable, but your milage may vary.
- The values of the matrix are "scanned" from the standard stream *and* checked at the same time. `m` is uninitialized, so that its values are indetermined. While setting the elements of, say, the first row, the code is trying to compare those with the last row, which is yet to be entered. It's necessary to performe the checks *after* all the elements are inputted.
- In C, array indices start from 0, while in this snippet the loop are like `for (i=1; i<=M; i++)`, skipping the first element and accessing one past the end (which has undefined behavior). The anti-diagonal should be defined by `i + j == M - 1`.

Comment: `for (i=0;i<M;i++){
  for (j=0;j<M;j++){
  scanf("%d", &m[i][j]);
    }
    }
    for (i=0;i<M;i++){
    for (j=0;j<M;j++){
        if ((i==j || i+j==M-1) && (m[i][j]==m[M-i+1][j])
        b=1;
    }
    }`

Comment: I tried to change that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Michael You oin't need a nested loop to check both diagonals, but you have to get the indices right: https://godbolt.org/z/bzdP4P